# Unable to use INDIRECT formula in VBA due to apostrophe in formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, apostrophe, excel-indirect

I am trying to write the following formula in VBA however, since the formula contains an apostrophe, the part after the apostrophe gets commented out.  Can anyone help please?

```
Dim LastcolGen As Long, lastrowfilter As Long 

Range(Cells(6, 10), Cells(lastrowfilter, LastcolGen)).Formula = _
 "IF(J$4="FactTrancheValue",INDEX(INDIRECT(J$4),ROW()-4,MATCH(J$5,INDIRECT("'"&J$4&"'!"&"A1:JJ1"),0)),INDEX(INDIRECT(J$4),MATCH(INDIRECT(J$3&ROW()),INDIRECT("'"&J$4&"'!"&"A1:A999999"),0),MATCH(J$5,INDIRECT("'"&J$4&"'!"&"A1:JJ1"),0)))" 
Range(Cells(6, 10), Cells(lastrowfilter, LastcolGen)).Select 
Selection.Copy 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Thanks,
AB

Comment: Cam you please show us the VBA code that you are using to create this Function?

Comment: @AJD - Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Double quotes in VBA strings need to be escaped by doubling them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested)

```
Range(Cells(6, 10), Cells(lastrowfilter, LastcolGen)).Formula = _
    "=IF(J$4=""FactTrancheValue"",INDEX(INDIRECT(J$4)," & _
    "ROW()-4,MATCH(J$5,INDIRECT(""'""&J$4&""'!""&""A1:JJ1""),0))," & _
    "INDEX(INDIRECT(J$4),MATCH(INDIRECT(J$3&ROW())," & _
    "INDIRECT(""'""&J$4&""'!""&""A1:A999999""),0)," & _
    "MATCH(J$5,INDIRECT(""'""&J$4&""'!""&""A1:JJ1""),0)))"
```

(edited according to your update)

When setting that formula to a single cell I get no errors from VBA (though the formula itself returns #REF!)

If this doesn't work then make sure your `Range()` reference is correct.

Comment: Results in the following error:
"Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: I can't test right now - Debug.Print the formula to the Immediate pane then copy and paste into the worksheet - Excel will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Okay, I tried however, not very sure about how quotes are used in excel.  Whenever you may find some time, please help debug.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What value is in J4 ?  Looks like it should be a sheet name, but then you have `INDEX(INDIRECT(J$4),...` which doesn't seem valid

Comment: J4 has a value equal to a named range in the workbook.

Comment: Seems more like a problem with your formula (which is not my strong point).  If you can get that working in a cell and update your question with the working formula, I can help you translate that.

Comment: Have updated my question.  This formula works when entered in a cell.

Comment: I can't replicate your setup, but I've edited my code above.  If it still doesn't work then I'm out of suggestions.